# how to implement a class bindings in js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, class, animation

I just started front-end, want to implement a dark mode animation.

When you click the switch(a rope), the page will change theme.

but I don't know how to add the animation by using js like vue's class binding.

```css
@keyframes line {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.pull {
  animation: line 0.5s;
}
```

just like this in vue(I found it online)

```js
<div
  class="switch"
  :class="{ 'pull': inAnimation }"
  @animationend="animationEnd"
  @click="changeTheme"
/>
```

This is my code.

I don't konw how to use js to complete it.

```js
const sw = document.getElementById('switch');

const changeTheme = () => {
  sw.addEventListener("click", () => {
    sw.className = 'pull';
    if (document.body.className !== "dark") {
      document.body.classList.add("dark");
      localStorage.setItem("css", "dark");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("dark");
      localStorage.removeItem("css");
    }
    sw.className = '';
  });

  if (localStorage.getItem("css")) {
    document.body.className = "dark";
    document.body.classList.add("dark");
  }
  
};

changeTheme();
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Mancuoj/pen/zYdpVrV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I see that you miss the id the element because you're using `getElementById`,
it has to be like:

```
<div
  id="switch" <!-- this is missing -->
  class="switch"
  :class="{ 'pull': inAnimation }"
  @animationend="animationEnd"
  @click="changeTheme"
/>
```

Then, Based on using Vue or not. (If Vue, setup the code in same component as in the element above).

**Vue**

```
<script>

export default {
    mounted() {
        const sw = document.getElementById('switch');
        sw.addEventListener("click", () => {
            sw.classList.add('pull');
            if (!document.body.classList.contains("dark")) {
            document.body.classList.add("dark");
            localStorage.setItem("css", "dark");
            } else {
            document.body.classList.remove("dark");
            localStorage.removeItem("css");
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
              sw.classList.remove("pull")
            }, 600);
        });

        if (localStorage.getItem("css")) {
            document.body.classList.add("dark");
        }   
    }
}
</script>
```

if **Vanilla Js**

```
const sw = document.getElementById("switch");
if (sw) {
  const changeTheme = () => {
    sw.addEventListener("click", () => {
      sw.classList.add("pull");
      if (!document.body.classList.contains("dark")) {
        document.body.classList.add("dark");
        localStorage.setItem("css", "dark");
      } else {
        document.body.classList.remove("dark");
        localStorage.removeItem("css");
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        sw.classList.remove("pull");
      }, 600);
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem("css")) {
      document.body.classList.add("dark");
    }
  };
  changeTheme();
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/Mancuoj/pen/zYdpVrV  it does not work

Comment: I just updated my answer copy the JS code again and try it and it should work as you want it.
I tried the updated code in Codepen and it worked fine 